# How did people get apps on their computer before the Internet?

Tags: history, market, application-program

The Internet has existed since the 90s, but how did people get apps and games installed on their computers before that and how were they accessed and saved?

Comment: AOL sent at least one CD per day via snail mail. Or you bought a cassette with your software of choice from your neighborhood computer store and listened to it attempting to load. Or download from the local BBS at <=2400 baud.

Comment: Some people took the time to type in multiple pages of source code that were printed in books and magazines.

Comment: In the 90s/early 00s, you would buy software, which came on CD or floppy, at a computer store. Before this, you bought cassettes or typed it in from books or magazines.

Comment: 2400' [magtape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic-tape_data_storage).

Comment: We used to pour raw bits into cardboard boxes and ship them to customers.  We even included a short manual with some instructions!

Comment: I feel old. Very old.

Comment: The same way you would buy any computer hardware from a computer store...unless you're completely unfamiliar with what discs, CDs, and DVDs are. Then I got nothing.

Comment: @MichaelGraf So do I after reading this question and I am **_23_**

Comment: in the 80s, if you were lucky, there was at least one guy in your school, who had the same computer you had, owning 2 floppy disk drives, and countless floppy disks

Comment: People didn't get apps on their computer, because software wasn't called apps.

Comment: _"how did people get apps and games installed on their computers before"_ → Exactly the same way people get most games for their Nintendo Switch **today**.

Comment: [When I was a boy, every packet was delivered by carrier pigeon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ov9p8FsHHx4)

Comment: My first regular job was as a programmer back in 1969.  The computer vendor released software on magtape reels about 2400 feet long.  There were a few items that were released on paper tape, notably the read-in mode bootstrap loader.

Comment: The term "app" is used in an anachronistic way here; before the advent of internet I don't think anybody would have recognised the word. Initially software was a collection of programs, "application programs" emerged as a subcategory, which at some point (maybe in the 1980's) became abbreviated "application". But as far as I can remember "app" only took off with the advent of smartphones.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen the term _app_ as an abbreviation of _application_ existed long before smartphones, though in my memory it was only a term used by computer enthusiasts, while smartphones later made it common parlance. I didn't dig too far in looking, but the definition of _killer app_ was an issue in the Microsoft antitrust lawsuit, which means it had been around for some time. I'm guessing it goes back to at least the 80s.

Comment: Back in the day we had "internet on a disc" kind of thing. Some computer magazines publisher will compose a webpage with computer news and software, and save it on a (pressed) CD. The readers can read news and "download" software from this "website on a disc". I stopped buying those CDs after 2003 when I finally had home internet but I've heard of USB thumb drive versions of this ~5 years afterwards.

Comment: If you're wondering how the installed apps would run on old machines, very early machines would simply run a disk software when inserted in the machine.  Later machines would use a command prompt like Microsoft's DOS and you would type in a command to run the app.  Later on, Windows and other GUI software would let you access apps with a double-click, but even early Windows software would need you to type in a command to run them from the DOS prompt.

Comment: @LioElbammalf The iPoAC protocol is documented on [RFC1149](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1149). Implementation details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers).

Comment: @doneal24 Indeed, I believe that is what the song is referring to.

Comment: I'd like to point out that that they weren't called "apps" until about a decade ago. Up until smartphones and tablets hit the market, they were universally called "programs". And, as someone above noted, for the many of the earliest home computers (such as my first TSR-80), you would write most of the programs yourself. Things got a lot easier in the mid 80s and early 90s when the market for home computers led to a lot of retailers carrying computer programs as boxed sets like the one pictured above.

Comment: The Internet has existed since 1969.  Did you not see the celebrations for its 50th anniversary a couple of years ago?  I first used in in 1982.  It is the WWW that has only existed since the 1990s.

Comment: Sometimes in the 90s, when yours truly was in charge of the math department PC classroom, I simply shooed all the students away, and started installing MSWord. First insert disk #1, then disk #2 (and insert disk #1 to the next computer) etc. 10 computers, 10 "floppies". Took a while :-)

Comment: We used SneakerNet. That is to say that we physically took our media (floppies, usually) from computer-to-computer by walking.

Comment: It's a multistep process.  First you implement some network protocols. Then you standardize them.  Next, wait for other implementations.  Eventually, the company whose software you want to buy will have a network presence. Simple, eh?

Comment: Before WWW, I have used punch cards, 110 baud terminals, cassette tape, ARCnet, 10 MB HD cartridge, 320 MB 8" HDD, ST506 HDDs, Apple ][ floppies,  CDROMs, and dial-up BBS to install the software. I worked for a company in the early80's that invented streaming game service on cable TV using the VITs line of video with 4Mbps and streaming games for VIC20, TRS80,  ][+ with interactive service and demo'd in Vegas at Cablecon.   Getting onto the 1st web was like crawling on broken glass with low-level protocols.

Comment: Buying games on optical media is still common.

Comment: It's not really an answer in itself, but an insight into the app-distribution industry of the 80s/90s might be found in Jeff Vogel's "Failing to Fail" GDC talk. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stxVBJem3Rs He talks about having people literally call him up and mail-order his games from his house at one point!

Comment: I don't currently have the rep to answer, but an additional method used in the UK was telesoftware (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telesoftware). The BBC transmitted data that could be picked up by the BBC Micro computer using a special adapter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC_Micro_expansion_unit#Teletext_adapter)

Comment: They’re called ‘applications’ on the very first page of Inside Macintosh Vol. 1 from 1984; for customers of at least one vendor it’s been a recognised term for almost 40 years.

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD.](https://xkcd.com/1755/)

Comment: "...their computer". When I first got involved in the late 1960s, people didn't own computers: universities, governments, and corporations owned computers, and they hired operators and systems programmers to look after them. This of us who wrote programs depended on compilers and other software that had been supplied by the manufacturer.

Comment: Before the Internet we didn't need such frequent upgrades, as there was no need to patch software to stop bad actors trying to hack into the system.

Comment: @molo [& Marc van Leeuwen but I can't add 2 tags] - whilst true that *most* OSes used the term 'program' rather than 'app', Mac has used 'app', as in 'Application', since at least the beginning of the 90s. We old hands thought it quite a liberty that the rest of the interwebz in general 'stole' our idea with the advent of smartphones. We still got them on floppies back then, but they were always 'apps'.

Comment: [Over the radio?](https://radiolab.org/episodes/mixtape-cassetternet)

Comment: Re the age of the abbreviation "app": GEM used ".APP" as a file extension for executables that made particular use of GEM's WIMP capabilities: <https://www.manualslib.com/manual/822697/Atari-Faicon030.html?page=105#manual>.

Comment: My first computer an Atari 8bit came with an OS and a build in basic. So also without a disk station/cassette recorder you could play and learn how to program with this computer. We bought magazines & books and copied programs they was printed in source. Also programs/games came on cartridges. Disks were shared and copied. We met to program together. Really nice time.

Comment: The first computers mostly used paper tape. Later on IBM came with punched cards.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

People used storage media, which they carried around to the machines they wanted to use the software on. The same way music and video were physically distributed in the late 20th century on tape and CD.

Very early on, programs and data were stored on paper tape and punched cards. Then magnetic tape. Then floppy disks. Then CD-ROMs. Even cartridges containing semiconductor memory were sometimes used, particularly for game consoles. (Now that I think about it, we still use cartridges as USB flash drives.)

You might get your software directly from the computer manufacturer. The OS usually came this way. Early on, most software was custom and written by the user (often a large company). Then custom software houses started popping up. Much stuff was ordered in the mail, especially before retail computer stores existed in every major town.

Small computer stores selling software, parts, etc., used to be everywhere, at least in Canada. They're much less common now, relatively speaking. There were two within walking distance, where I lived in the 1990s and was in the suburbs! Computers failed more often, technology was moving faster, and people didn't order as much online then. You might visit the computer store several times per year if you have the budget, often to buy the software.

Here's Windows 98, out of the box, as you might buy for a machine without any operating system on it:

[image: Windows 98]

Included is a paper manual, a registration card to mail off to Microsoft, a credit for some free Internet service, and Windows 98 itself: the boot floppy (for computers that could not boot from CD) and the Windows 98 install CD.

By this point (1998), floppy disks were too small to hold most major software releases and were limited to boot disks and small files such as device drivers. Network distribution was also common by then, but many people were on dial-up. (Windows 98 would take days to download at that speed.) The disc itself is nearly full, with Windows taking several hundred megabytes and the rest being movies and music bonus content. Before long, it would not be uncommon to have an entire set of CDs to install software, echoing the sets of floppies sometimes seen in the 80s and early 90s. Then higher density DVDs were used.

It's worth noting that plenty of people "borrowed" such kits from a friend rather than buying them themselves. Floppies, and then much later, CDs, could also be duplicated by the user. Software piracy is not new, and with commercial software, various steps were taken to combat that. For example, you might need to enter codes from the manual that were uniquely matched to the disc in the same kit.

The Internet started competing against physically distributing media (not just for software, but film and music and everything else too) in the 2000s, finally coming to dominate in the last ten years or so.

Comment: I still have the box (but not the diskettes) that contained MS Office for Windows 3.1 and IIRC there were about twelve 3½" diskettes.

Comment: Even as late as 2010-2015 one could find CDs and DVDs with games and popular software (Windows, Microsoft Office) in retail stores. Even Windows Vista was marketed on DVDs.

Comment: @vsz Windows 8 was the last Windows to be marketed on disc. I know, because I have a physical disc copy of that. With Windows 10 physical copies they switched to using USB drives.

Comment: I remember software spread over 8 floppy disks.  *Please insert disk 5/8*

Comment: Note that cartridges can also still be used for Nintendo Switch games

Comment: There also used to be big computer software *conventions* where various disks were sold to visitors - this was also where you could get certain demo disks (sometimes called Freeware or Shareware) that would contain multiple demos of various software (usually games).

Comment: "as you might buy for a machine without any operating system on it" which was how 99.99% of computers were sold. You might get a copy of an OS bundled with it, but you still had to install it yourself.

Comment: @gerrit I seem to recall installing at least one app that involved 20+ 3.5" floppies. I can't recall what it was though.

Comment: Never underestimate the bandwidth of a station wagon full of mag-tapes!

Comment: Coincidentally, during this time period, Microsoft dodged $40 billion in taxes by structuring itself as a Puerto Rican manufacturer that manufactured boxes with CDs inside them, with a loss-making RD center in Redmond.

Comment: @JakeRobb I recall installing applications which took 50+ floppies. Like you I can't recall what they were though

Comment: @WeatherVane I found a complete set of 3.11 floppies in the skip at work. They were my path to buying "upgrade" versions of win95 / 98 later on

Comment: @NomadMaker I recall an actual assignment of comparing the bandwidth of a Pony Express rider with his saddlebags filled with floppy disks against a wired data connection.  The rider was remarkably competitive (in the 90's).

Comment: @vsz Your timeframe doesn't quite match. Windows Vista was released in 2007, Windows 7 in 2009, and Windows 8 in 2012. So "Even Windows Vista was marketed on DVDs" is not aligned with "Even as late as 2010-2015".

Comment: @JakeRobb I know I've installed Windows 95 from diskettes. [Raymond Chen said they were 13 high-density disks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050819-10/?p=34513). Of course you had double that amount, just in case any of them failed. It was a whole-afternoon plan.

Comment: @NomadMaker the bandwidth is great but the ping is diabolical :-)

Comment: @nanoman : that was one example. Even if Windows Vista itself was no longer available in retail stores near the end of the timeframe I mentioned, many others still were. Especially games, but also Office packages.

Comment: @NomadMaker thanks for that great quote from Tanenbaum, Intro OS, on minix, from around 1990. Minix came on something like 6 floppies, to be downloaded with ftp from the internet, accessible only at the local university

Comment: I can speak to memories of using our Radio Shack Tandy Color Computer 2 where attaching the 5.25" floppy drive was an upgrade to previously having cartridges, and doing loading and saving via a tape recorder. And then, of course, there were the programs of dozens of pages that my brother typed in from *Rainbow* magazine...

Comment: I remember installing Word Perfect on my dad's machine.  It was over 20 disks.  It actually came with a case to hold them all.

Comment: Windows 95 (original release) was ~35MB. It came in either 13 special DMF floppies, or on CD - in which case you'd get a lot of filler, include a video of the song "Good Times" by Edie Brickell. Windows 98 was ~100MB.
Also in my case, we had a parallel-port-attached external HD to distribute stuff to computers without CD drives.

Comment: @NomadMaker: Also relevant: [xkcd's what if - FedEx Bandwidth](https://what-if.xkcd.com/31)

Comment: In essence, it's the same way you get software today, without the Internet, except they had different kinds of media to put it on, and they weren't so centered on updates. Don't forget, though, books of BASIC code where you could type out the code for the games yourself and then play them. Don't forget that audiocassettes (the same ones used for music) could be used like discs.

Comment: I'm not saying it never happened, but I don't recall ever having to type in any codes to get a program to work until after the Internet arrived (it was popular with Shareware, Windows operating systems, Microsoft Office, antivirus programs, and programs that cost loads of money, but not too much with games and things). In the 1980s, it seemed like most people just used their computers to play video games, make greeting cards, and a few other things. Word processing didn't seem too common until DOS became popular (we used Norton Textra Writer).

Answer (score 51):

People are focusing on floppies and tapes.  But the question is literally tagged with floppy-disk, so pointing them out may not be that helpful. The more general answer perhaps is that you went to a physical store.  Almost everybody had bought their computer at a physical store, so at very least they could go back to that same store to buy some software without much of a discovery process.

In the 90's, every small town had multiple places that sold software in boxes as a physical product.  Radio Shack was ubiquitous here in the US, and it always had some shareware disks or the like.  At peak, that one brand had something like 8000 total stores, and the US has about 5000 towns with at least 5000 people.  There were several other brands of small retail stores like Electronics Boutique and Egghead Software that would fit in a small retail storefront, strip mall, or small shop in a large shopping mall.  There were also a ton of small independent or local stores in many places.

Big-Box consumer electronics stores like Best Buy and Circuit City were a little less common than the small stores since they were physically larger.  But they were also pretty common.  There were something like 2000 Best Buy stores at peak.

Past that, I can remember seeing occasional software at grocery and drug stores in the mid 90's.  It wasn't a major staple or anything.  But by that point the market was large enough that you'd occasionally see family friendly shareware games or some crappy third tier desktop publishing software for making "Welcome Home" banners.  Department stores like Target always had an electronics section that stocked at least an aisle of PC games.  Bookshops often had a software section as well.  Buy our book on how to use Turbotax...  And also buy Turbotax, was a pretty common kind of bundle deal.

Grocery stores, book stores, news stands, etc., also had an aisle full of magazines.  Among The New Yorker and Guns Today or whatever, you would also see Nintendo Power, Mac User, Amiga Format, Byte, etc.  All of those magazines would have ads so you could order stuff by mail.

It was definitely harder to find software in the 80's when computing was much more of a niche hobby.  You might need to go to a nearby big city to find a specialist store until the late 80's.  But by the 90's, software was kind of ubiquitous.  In a developed country like the US the majority of households had a computer by the end of the 90's, so it was just a huge market for any retailer to ignore.

So by the 90's, a typical computer user would probably have dozens of places they could potentially buy games and other software from, with something like a reasonable drive to a mall a town or two over on a weekend.  You go, pay $20 - $50 to get a Big Box.  The box would have a manual, a tape or floppy in the 80's, floppies or a CD in the 90's.  Stick it in the computer, and click "setup" or type "install" or whatever the process was for that app on that computer, and off to the races.  If you had one of the three supported models of Dot Matrix printers, you could print a Welcome Home banner with your choice of a clip art duck or a clip art dog 20 minutes after you got home from the store.

Comment: Don't forget software retailers such as Babbages's, Software Etc., and ComputerLand. Every decently sized mall in America had a software store.

Comment: And also way back when, some magazines would publish the code and you'd type that in to your computer manually. Line. By. Line.

Comment: Also mail order software was around as long as mail order hardware and both were pervasive in the 1980s too,

Comment: I know that it's tongue-in-cheek when you talk about the banners printed on dot matrix printers. But your answer gives the wrong impression that this technology was still relevant in the mid-1990s. By that time, dot matrix printers had almost completely been superseded by inkjet printers, not least due to the highly successful HP DeskJet 500 in 1990 (the color version was introduced in 1991). Virtually the only application in which dot matrix printers were still somewhat relevant by 1995 was printing on fan-fold paper – which might include banners after all, now that I think about it.

Comment: +1 for old retail stores, which I felt was the crux of the question. I kinda miss walking into a store and seeing all the PC game boxes. (That said, it's super nice to buy a new computer and just redownload everything from Steam at like 80 Mb/s.)

Comment: Office supply stores were a big one for me growing up. My Staples had a few large aisles dedicated to computer hardware, and a fairly sizeable area for software on cds.

Comment: @BrianH Yes, mail order catalogs were very important, in the '90s, most had Mac and PC versions. So you had MacWarehouse and PCWarehouse (where if you called to order, you could probably find a picture of the person you were speaking with on one of the pages in the catalog!) - although, after they were big, the blonde MacWarehouse covergirl probably no longer answered the phones. Other important ones were MacConnection/PCConnection and MacMall/PCMall.

Comment: I remember we looked at games (a CD in a pretty box) in toy stores in the '90s/'00s. At some point you could also borrow them from the library. There were also CDs with like 50 games on it, mostly demo versions where you could only play the first level and they hoped you would order the full version. (via the phone or something, we never did that) Also illegal copies from friends/family on 3.5" floppies and later CDs were popular.

Comment: @Schmuddi: I remember still printing school papers on dot-matrix in 1996, but that was more of a "Dad was a cheapskate" thing than non-existence of better technology.

Comment: @Schmuddi banners were a big deal back in the day.  And you could only effectively generate them with fan-fold paper.  Ink jet printers didn't use fan-fold paper, but dot matrix printers did.

Comment: The bit about software being a niche product through the 80s is probably accurate for the US, but less so in the UK and the rest of Europe, where home computing was a big thing from the early 80s. Software was available in a wide range of high-street shops - newsagents like WH Smith, pharmacists like Boots, and even local tobacconists as well. Though I don't know what proportion of software sold would have been productivity software as opposed to games, which were of course the most common use for 80s home computers.

Answer (score 33):

1. Typed them in from magazines and books, saved them on tape or floppy.
2. Get software by loading it from a tape or floppy borrowed from a friend/colleague/school/club and copy it to yourself.
3. Use a modem to download or upload from a bulletin board system.
4. Buy commercial games/programs on tape/floppy.

Comment: I used to write my own software - much more interesting. But then I was never interested in games.

Comment: These I've also done: (5) Plugged in the code using switches and a deposit switch. Sometimes this code was the bootstrap needed for external media. Sometimes, it was the entire program. (6) Hand-soldered the program (hard-wired for real!) (7) Used a [Cauzin reader](https://rich12345.tripod.com/museum2/softstrip.html). I still have mine. ;)

Comment: Regarding 1: Nothing like typing in several pages of code and then trying to figure out which typo was causing the program to crash.

Comment: @No'amNewman writing your own software has always been more gratifying.  Games weren't off the table either.  I remember one time when I had a day at work with nothing to do, so I wrote my own version of Breakout.

Comment: @aslum: I still remember the joy of *Rainbow* magazine including a checksum function that at least told you the likely line number for the error.

Answer (score 28):

Several ways depending on the era which you are talking about:

1. I have some really old commercial software that came on 8" floppy disk.  These are pretty rare today but were quite common in the pre-IBM PC days: [image: 8" Floppy Disk]
2. After that, and a lot due to the introduction of the Apple II, the Commodore PET, and then the IBM PC, the 5.25" floppy disk came to dominate.  Very similar to the earlier 8" disks but smaller:[image]
3. Next came the 3.5" "floppy" disk.  The media was floppy but the hard plastic case made the overall unit not floppy:[image: 3.5" floppy]
4. After that, downloads from dial-up systems started taking over.  File repositories on "FidoNet" Bulletin Board Systems, CompuServe, AOL, and others started being used for distributing software especially "shareware" and "demo" software.  Around the same time, CDROM also became a distribution media and that continues to this day:[image]
5. After that, the internet began to evolve as a viable, and inexpensive with near immediate fulfillment, method of software distribution.

There are, of course, some other methods which were used.  The earliest consumer programs were printed in magazines and you typed in the code, some commercial software was distributed on "magnetic tape" usually targeted at mainframe/minicomputer systems.  There were, and still are, some other magnetic tape formats usually in cartridge formats.

And we cannot forget Cassette Tape format!

I still have a cassette with "MicroChess" for the KIM-1:

[image: MicroChess - KIM-1]

Comment: When they first came out, CD-ROMs contained such a huge amount of data it was *near* un-imaginable.  At least compared to floppy disks (and consumer tape).  Home PCs were still commonly using both 5.25" and 3.5" floppies (1.2 / 1.4 MiB).  I remember being amazed, copying from a ~650 MiB CDROM archive of "shareware" onto floppy disks. (At the university library.)

Comment: There were also some types of storage media that bridged the transition from floppy disks to CDROM drives such as the [Zip drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_drive). I never owned one myself, but the software company that I worked for as a student used them for backups, and I *think* they also used commercial software that was distributed on Zip drives (or perhaps it was pirated software?).

Comment: @Schmuddi  I considered adding the Zip drive, and I actually still have one, but I am not aware of any commercial or shareware software that was distributed on them.

Comment: "hard floppies"

Comment: Don't forget that each physical iteration of disc also had multiple densities. Your photo of a 3.5" floppy has "HD" in the corner, which means it's a double-sided, high-density floppy with a capacity of ~1.4MB (+/- a bit depending on how it's formatted). There were single-side, low-density floppies that could only store 360kb but were physically identical aside the HD badge. CDs also varied in size, although not as widely! There were even double-sided DVDs which had to be ejected and flipped over (until the drives gained support).

Comment: @JakeRobb  I'm not sure that the OP was looking for every possible variation of every possible media category.  But you are indeed correct.  I'll also note that some vendors, Apple, Commodore, and Digital Equipment come to mind, used proprietary disk formats.

Comment: *tsk tsk* for posting disc pics without their sleeves on ;)

Comment: You should also mention the [Cauzin Softstrip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Dlfpab1Knc)

Comment: I also neglected to mention Hollerith Cards, paper tape, and front panel switches.

Comment: @Kingsley In the mid-'90s I used to go to a computer shop in the next city and pay GB£0.50 per floppy for shareware copied from a CD like that.

Answer (score 14):

As far as the question is not limited to commercial software, here's an alternative view.

Before the advent of the internet or any widely used long distance packed-switched networks, long distance data distribution among UNIX computers was achieved using a store-and-forward system called [UUCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUCP), which facilitated, among other things, distribution of [discussion groups (Usenet)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet).

It was a distributed (without a single main server, unlike a BBS) discussion board system with hundreds if not thousands of various "newsgroups", some of which were used to distribute source code (partially archived at [comp.sources.*](https://groups.google.com/search/groups?q=comp.sources)), either platform-specific in an appropriately named group, or portable enough across different CPU architectures and UNIX-like platforms to be compilable and usable with little effort.

Comment: And binaries ([uuencoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) into text) as multi-part posts in newgroups under `alt.binaries.*`.  That part of usenet still exists today, mostly used to distribute "warez", aka pirated software and audio or video files.  Many ISPs that still have news servers don't carry those groups, anymore, though.

Answer (score 13):

One method wasn't mentioned here: **radio broadcasting**.
The official Czechoslovak Radio used to broadcast a special night show for computer freaks in the late eighties, and it ended with a few short programmes for **ZX Spectrum**, which the listeners could record on audio tape and then `LOAD ""`

Comment: Yep, same in Yugoslavia. We'd also order the tape cassettes with games from the bootleggers that were posting their ads in various computer and gaming magazines. Or we'd just go to the flea market on Sunday morning and meet them in person :-)

Comment: I came here to write this, and then I found your answer! On top of all complications of this process, my tape recorder had this *bass/treble* dial, if you didn't put it in the perfect position you could not load the radio recording...

Comment: How reliable was this? On my old ZX Spectrum even tape-to-tape copying on the same dual-tapedeck could be an iffy proposition.

Comment: @DrMcCleod Very poor, indeed, *R Tape Loading Error* was common. Perhaps that was the reason why they withdrew it from air after a couple of months.

Comment: In Germany, we had also [Channel Videodat](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_Videodat) (Wikipedia page unfortunately only in German), which used a modulated video signal during the vertical blank interval. That "space" was otherwise used for [teletext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletext).

Answer (score 12):

The internet has existed since the 1960s, the World Wide Web is a 1990s development. 'Apps' is used to refer to software obtained via curated 'Stores', like the Apple App Store and the Google Play store. Other than Steam, those didn't exist before the late 2000's. In general, the term is 'software'.

We used cassette tape and floppy disks, or we downloaded from bulletin boards over the phone. We typed programs in from listings in books and magazines. Sometimes we even got software broadcast over television via Teletext services like CEEFAX.

Comment: Well, we may not have had 'Apps' but we had 'Applications'. When phones came out, they were too small for Applications, so they were shortened to 'Apps'. :)

Comment: And the internet did *not* exist in the 1960s. Arpanet started in 1969, but that was a far cry from the internet.

Comment: Don't forget 'applets', mini applications that could be embedded inside webpages!

Comment: @dbmag9, I think we would all prefer to forget those. Are you going to bring up Flash next?

Comment: I never even heard "application" until I moved from 8 and 16 bit machines to Windows in the '90s. I found it quite an ugly term. Everyone I knew in the home computer scene until then just said "program" or "software".

Comment: @JakeRobb this comment section is an applet - although not the traditional kind. This one is written in Javascript.

Comment: "The internet has existed since the 1960s" - not for most people.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Internet "the emergence of architecture such as the Domain Name System, and the adoption of TCP/IP internationally on existing networks marked the beginnings of the Internet. Commercial Internet service providers (ISPs) emerged in **1989** in the United States and Australia."

Comment: @user25371 I'm not familiar with SO's implementation, but having been developing web apps for 20+ years, I suspect it's more accurate to think of the entire site as one large application with many components and functions; not multiple little, separate applications.

That said, I was not talking about applets in the general, dictionary definition sense. Rather, I was referring to [the HTML applet tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/applet). I suspect dbmag9 was too.

Answer (score 11):

Just to toss a log on the fire.

One of the more novel mechanics in terms of mass distribution was through an optical scanning device.

Specifically, this was a device, about a foot long, that you plugged into your computer. It was a mini scanner. The sensor was about an inch wide, and moved down the track, like a normal flat bed scanner without the bed. And it wasn't a generic pixel scanner, it only scanned the encoded images, like a barcode or QR code scanner.

Dr Dobbs actually published these in their magazine for, perhaps, about a year or so.

Edit:

After some research and help from a fellow on another forum, this is the device I'm talking about:

Cauzin Softstrip https://rich12345.tripod.com/museum2/softstrip.html

Edit 2:

Ha! I found it!

Go to page 711 within https://archive.org/details/dr_dobbs_journal_vol_11/page/710/mode/2up and you'll see the softstrip images. I simply wasn't looking late enough, October '86. I was looking through '85 and early 86.

On page 693, they mention what they're doing.

Also, at a time there was some software distributed in magazines on flimsy 45 RPM records. And, I believe, at some point there were radio broadcasts of software that were meant to be recorded and loaded into a computer.

Comment: Do you have more details of this scanner device? Maybe the name? It sounds fascinating. (If it's too much for this answer, I can ask a separate question.)

Comment: Yes, can you explain more how this worked. You'd buy a magazine or book with encoded images and the scanner would convert it to computer code?

Comment: I actually had one, won it as a prize somewhere, I think at a Mac show at school. But I don't recall the name. As I said, it was about a foot long, 1.5" + wide, made of brown plastic. I tried looking through some of the old Dr Dobbs, but I can't find any yet where they have the scan codes. But I almost sense that some of the pages that had them, had them removed before they published them. Hard to say.

Comment: @WaterMolecule Yes, you could easily fit 4 "bars" of coded data across a normal page. In the Dr Dobbs articles, they had one row per page next to the source code. You'd scan it in and get a text file -- at least for the source code, but nothing to stop you from using it for binary.

Comment: @WillHartung well that's an improvement on typing TRS-80 BASIC code character for character from a magazine.

Comment: @WaterMolecule Indeed. I recall seeing those black pages of TRS-80 BASIC program listings. I've looked through the DDJ "best of" volumes they published, and its clear they removed these. In fact, they've removed I would say 99% of the advertising in these as well, so they likely did it then. They clearly removed entire pages, so they may have removed the page mentioning that they were doing this at all. I got the device probably in 1985, and it was after that that they did it.

Comment: If you look at the DDJ Volume 11, 1986 edition. In the first (January) issue. Look at the "C Chest" program listings and note the large amounts of white space on each side of the page. I'm pretty sure that's where these bars were. It could have been all advertising, but historically, they didn't wrap their code in advertising. Circumstantial evidence here to be sure, but that's all I have for the moment.

Comment: You should totally link an image of a SoftStrip.

Comment: ISTR, some of the published software was "copy protected" by printing the bar codes on a dark red background. The scanner could distinguish the black ink from the red background, but photo copiers of the day would only give you a solid black page if you tried to copy it.

Comment: This seems to be an extension of using conventional barcode scanners to input programs from paper, e.g. the HP-41C calculator had a [barcode wand accessory](https://literature.hpcalc.org/items/354), circa 1979. Also of note, this idea was resurrected for the Gameboy Advance as the [Nintendo e-Reader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_e-Reader).

Comment: The Cauzin scanner cost about $200 (the equivalent of $550 today). It was a nice idea, but not too many people bought them.

Answer (score 10):

Plenty of answers here detailing how to get your hands on some physical medium with a piece of software on it, but I don't see any of them touching on the point of

> how did people get apps and games installed on their computers [...] and how were they accessed and saved?

So, there were several ways. In the very early days, before my time (aka in the 70s and 80s) computers often didn't have a hard drive in them. Each time you booted them up, you had to supply some physical media (a tape or a diskette) that contained the software. You put in the media and pressed the power button. The computer loaded the software in memory and you continued from there. This is quite similar to older game consoles that need to have a CD or a cartridge in, before you can do anything with them.

As the 90s rolled around, hard drives became cheap enough that most computers started to have them. Or maybe a bit earlier, as I said, this was before my time so I'm a bit murky on the dates. This meant that software could now be copied to the computer itself. Operating systems started to reside on the hard drive, while other software could still be run directly from an external media, or also copied to the hard drive. This copying part was known as "installing" and most software usually came with an extra "installer" program which ran directly from the disk and copied the software to the hard drive. A lot like installing an app on your phone, except you had to launch it manually from the physical media. Most also included and "uninstaller" program that you could later use to delete the software from your hard drive.

As for saving data - well, you also used either the same (or different) external media, or saved your files to the hard drive.

**Added:**

Also I should note that back then you had to be at least somewhat familiar with all the folders (directories) on your computer. Today when you install an app on your phone you have no idea where *exactly* its files are. It's just "somewhere on the phone". Similarly with saving files to "My Documents" or whatever. But back then you had to know at least the path to the executable file itself so that you could locate it and run it. And when you saved/loaded some files, you had to know where they are located too.

However that applies only if you had a filesystem to begin with, so that includes various disks and diskettes. Tapes were different, but I have no experience with those.

Comment: Good point! My first hard disk was more expensive than the complete computer. (30 MB for an Atari ST for 3000 bucks.)

Comment: My first two computers, Atari 800 and Tandy 2000 both came sans hard drive. But by the end of the 80s hard drives were a standard feature.

Comment: @thebusybee I had to pay 15 month' salary for a PC-XT with 10 MB HDD back in 1989 but I never regretted. Booting without waiting for a floppy to load DOS 3,0 was luxury. As it hasn't got realtime clock chip, I had to manually set date and time after each restart.

Comment: @vitsoft Actually, my first own computer (set aside programmable calculators) was self-designed and built, run an 8080 with 0,0009 GHz system clock, with 1 KB RAM, 20 keys and a 6-digit 7-segment LED as I/O. Yes, no ROMs, no "mass storage" (tape, floppy, HD, ...), no screen, no network. Boy, was this a great time, and I had so much fun with it! Best thing, I could afford it from one month' compensation of non-military service.

Answer (score 8):

Another aspect that no one has mentioned yet is, many computers had dial-up modems that worked over telephone landlines.  They worked by converting streams of data to sound, which was sent as a voice call, and back (*modem* originally was short for MODulator-DEModulator, although today it mostly means boxes that connect to cable and DSL internet).  These transmitted at a tiny fraction of the speed of the modern Internet (early ones might transmit only a few hundred bytes per second), but files were much smaller then, too.

Some people would get extra landlines to their homes and have a modem listen on them, which would pick up and connect any user who dialed up to a text-only forum called a Bulletin-Board System (BBS).  This would run a program that (like a console on Linux, Mac or Windows today) emulated a terminal with sixteen colors. this normally brought up a menu, but you could log in to leave messages, play some games (Rogue Trader being one of the most popular) and download files.  The vast majority of BBSes had only one landline with one modem, so users would need to be considerate and not hog the line.

In the U.S., the phone company would not normally charge extra for local calls, no matter how many you made or how long they lasted, even if someone were using the phone line all day, so all BBSes recruited from a local area code.  Some were free, and some charged a subscription fee.  They would advertise in computer ’zines, or I remember some stores having flyers with a list of local BBSes.  However, many would regularly call each other up, or exchange data through what was called the FidoNet.

When the Internet came along, most of these were replaced by dial-up Internet Service Providers.  There was an intermediate stage with proprietary networks that were nationwide, with offices in each area code where subscribers could make a local call and connect to a modem. AOL is the best-known, gave all its users Internet access in the mid-’90s, and eventually stopped offering dial-up service at all, instead charging for access to its subscriber-only chat rooms from the Internet.  Most phone companies have since replaced their old analog wires with Digital Subscriber Line (DSL) service, and now offer high-speed Internet connections over those.  Nevertheless, [a few BBSes have hung around, replacing their landline connections with Telnet-protocol connections to an Internet address.](https://www.pcmag.com/news/7-modern-bbses-worth-calling-today)

Today, add-ons for some vintage computers plug into the same ports as a vintage modem and emulate one.  A variant of that at the time was to connect two computers with a “null modem cable,” which simply connected the input pin of one computer’s serial port to the output pin of the other, and could be used for a sort of two-person LAN party.

Also, if you’re reading this site and have not seen *WarGames* yet, you absolutely should!

Comment: *let's play global thermonuclear war* ... on second thought, that might not be such a good idea right now

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Still topical as ever? Oh, that reminds me: check out [the true story, too. Stranger than fiction!](https://www.powells.com/book/cuckoos-egg-tracking-a-spy-through-the-maze-of-computer-espionage-9781416507789)

Comment: I read that several years ago. Didn't think of the connection though.

Comment: "modem originally was short for MODulator-DEModulator"  It still is. It is still necessary to modulate and demodulate signals sent over cable or DSL links, amongst others.

Answer (score 5):

There were a myriad number of ways that consumers would get software for their computers. You could buy physical media from a store, or by mail order, or by calling a toll-free number. You could download digital media from things like Usenet and BBS systems. People would copy software onto all kinds of media, from disks to audio cassette tapes. Software listings were found in some magazines that you could subscribe to monthly, quarterly, annually, or something else. It sounds crazy now, but back in the 1980's and perhaps earlier, you could go to various stores that sold magazines or electronics and find various code listings that you'd have to painstakingly type in one line at a time, sometimes for hundreds of lines. Before the day of the Internet, people came up with all kinds of creative ways to share and distribute software in various forms.

Answer (score 5):

*Way back*, you'd load a bootstrap loader into the computer using toggle switches on the front of the computer ).  The loader would read in an inital program via paper tape, typically from the paper tape reader on the side of the teletype that acted as the console.  That program might be a more sophisticated loader.  Finally you'd "boot" the computer.

Here is the front panel on a [PDP-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-8) [image: Front panel on a PDP-8]

Notice that the switches are group into 3 to a color.  That's because the PDP line used *Octal* (3 bits) rather than *Hex* (4 bits) as the number base.  You'd get the bit pattern right and then toggle the load (?? - it's been a while) switch.  Also note that there are 18 switches available, even though the PDP-8 is a 12 bit machine (sorry, I don't know why, PDP-8s are before even my time).

The "Rim Loader" bunch of octal numbers in the rectangle on the left is probably the bootstrap loader - all 32 instructions, each 12 bits long.

*Anecdote*

Legend at my first employer had it that a much bigger competitor was trying to move into our business (which was automation software for paper mills).  They used PDP-11s (I think) and much of their software was on paper tape.  They had just about finished up their system when they went home for the weekend.  The procedure was to stash the paper tape in a drawer in the computer cabinet, lock the cabinet and go home.

The computer used [magnetic core memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic-core_memory) (which was non-volatile), so it didn't need to be loaded from paper tape very often.

Over the weekend, something happened.  The paper tape caught on fire, burning the computer and effectively all the software.

We offered to get the customer up and running in less than a month.  Everyone in the company set to work taking a system they'd installed in another customer's mill and converting it to this company's needs.  The result was our first *product* (everything had been highly customized before that).

Our competitor stepped back from being our competitor after than.  But, 5 years later, they bought us.  The project manager (and the guy who'd locked the cabinet) ended up running the new subsidiary (and being my direct boss).  He heard references to this story many times.